# Does jQuery have any functions to scroll the client to the bottom of the view port?

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport

I want to animate a scroll to the bottom of the viewport with jQuery. Is there a plugin available which isn't overkill (i.e. without a huge feature set for this small task);

Is there a plugin available or a way to do this natively with jQuery?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

jQuery makes things like this so trivial that you just dont need a plugin. Example:

```
var x = 250; //insert your own formula to calculate where you want to scroll to in px
var t = 500; //arbitrary time in ms
$("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: x }, t);
```

Instead of `html,body` you can put any element which scrolls, like a div. `t` is the time in ms over which the animation will run and `x` is your position to scroll to in px. Note that this works with scrollLeft also but not scrollRight or scrollBottom (not a limitation of jQuery but JavaScript).

Comment: $("#log-output").animate({scrollTop: $("#log-output").height()}, 250); worked great for automagically scrolling to the bottom of a textarea. Thanks!

Comment: `$("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: $('body').css('height') }, 0);` scrolls down to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 8):

you can always do the following line to scroll an element to the bottom

```
$("body").attr({ scrollTop: $("body").attr("scrollHeight") });
```

Answer (score 5):

Check the [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin, you can scroll to determined positions (fixed or absolute), using selectors, DOM elements, and more...

Give a look to the [demos](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)...

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on the answers from Darko Z and CMS, here is what I used to animate scrolling to a specific element:

```
var target = $('#elem');
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 500);
```