# Is there a way, to scroll similar to scrollTop, just from the bottom?

Tags: jquery, html

We all know the solution to scroll to a position from the top of the viewport:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:240}, 'fast');
```

Is there a way to scroll similar to scrollTop, just from the bottom of the viewport?

What I want to do: on a click event the page should scroll to a div anywhere in the body, it should stop scrolling when the div has reached the bottom of the viewport, fully visible. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a combination of `.offset().top`, which is the offset of the element from the top of the document, and `$(window).height()`, which is the height of the viewport:

```
var b = $('myEle');
$('html').animate({scrollTop: b.offset().top - $(window).height() + b.outerHeight()});
```

Scrolling to the oft-used `.offset().top` position will get the block to move to the top of the screen, so we simply minus off the height of the viewport and add the height of the object to get it to shift to a position at the bottom of the user's viewport.

**See a simple demo here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/Xkj9s/**

Answer (score 1):

There's a [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight) property that tells you the amount you can scroll. So if you want to scroll 240 px from the bottom, use `scrollHeight - 240`, for example:

```
var elem = $('html');
elem.animate({ scrollTop: elem[0].scrollHeight - 240 }, 'fast');
```

[Example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ozayi3/edit)

Comment: This solution did not work for me. The page scrolls to the bottom everytime. When I use a greater amount, eg.- 1140 (900 is the page height + 240), it works, but with troubles when I want to scroll back. Strange.

Comment: @Thomasz: That's because `scrollHeight` does not take the window height into account, you need to subtract that if you want to scroll relative to the window.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this SO question:

- [Does jQuery have any functions to scroll the client to the bottom of the view port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661041/does-jquery-have-any-functions-to-scroll-the-client-to-the-bottom-of-the-view-por)